# Regularizing a $L^p(B)$ function in $B$ and in $\partial B$.

Tags: lp-spaces, regularization

Let $B_1=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^N:\ |x|<1\}$. Let $u\in L^p(B_1)$ with $p\in (1,\infty)$ and suppose that $u$ is also defined in the boundary of $B_1$ and satisfies $u_{|\partial B_1}\in L^p(\partial B_1)$, where I'm assuming the surface measure in $\partial B_1$.

I want to find a sequence $u_n\in C^\infty(\overline{B_1})$ such that $u_n\to u$ in $L^p(B_1)$ and $(u_n)_{|\partial B_1}\to u_{|\partial B_1}$ in $L^p(\partial B_1)$

I was trying to do something like this: Let $\epsilon>0$ be a small number and consider the ball $B_{1+\epsilon}$. Extend $u$ in $B_{1+\epsilon}$ by reflecting it along the radial axis and call it $v$. Let $h_\delta$ be a mollifier sequence  and define $$u_\delta(x)=(h_\delta\ast u)(x)=\int_{B_{1+\epsilon}}h_\delta(x-y)v(y)dy$$

The last sequence does converge to $u$ in $L^p(B_1)$ but I dont know how to argue with the boundary. For example, by using Fubini's theorem, I can show that for almost $t\in (0,1+\epsilon)$, there exist a subsequence of $u_\delta$ (not relabaled) such that $(u_n)_{|\partial B_t}\to u_{|\partial B_t}$ in $L^p(\partial B_t)$.

Any to how to go further or even another idea is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend $u$ to  $B_2$ so that $u(x)=u(x/|x|)$ when $1<|x|<2$. Show that the sequence $v_n(x)=u(x/(1-n^{-1}))$ converges to $u$ in  $L^p(B_1)$. (Same proof as for continuity of translations in $L^p$.)  Then convolve $v_n$ with a mollifier $\varphi_n$ whose support contained in $B_{1/n}$. On the boundary $|x|=1$, the value of $v_n*\varphi_n$ is obtained by averaging the boundary values of $u$, and therefore will be close to $u|_{\partial B_1}$.

For example, consider $u=0$ on $(-1,1)$, $u(\pm 1)=1$.

Step 1: Extension

[image: extended]

Step 2: Scaling

[image: scaled]

Step 3: Mollification

[image: mollified]

Comment: Sorry to ask you @75064, but why the same argument does not work with $u\ast \varphi_n$?

Comment: @Tomás Consider this example: $u(x)=0$ when $|x|<1$, $u(x)=1$ when $|x|=1$. If you simply extend $u$ by $1$ outside of the ball and mollify the extension, the boundary values of convolution will be $\approx 1/2$. ¶ If you follow the approach I described, the boundary values are exactly $1$.

Comment: Possibly I am doing wrong calculation, but I can't get ypur result. For example in dimension 1 we have that $\int_{(-1/n,1/n)}u_n(1-y)\varphi_n(y)=\int_{(-1/n,0)}\varphi_n(y)dy=1/2$

Comment: @Tomás I added an illustrated example to my answer.